# How to allocate the given Url to a specific folder in my localhost in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, ubuntu-12.10

I have two folder in my localhost `var/www/project1` and `var/www/project2`

When I access one project url I want to get that site only how can I achieve that?

ex:

```
`project1.example.com` should go to the `project1/index.php`

`project2.example.com` should go to the `project2/index.php`
```

How can I achieve this? Is there any thing to change in apache or httpd.conf ?

Is there any redirection rules in apache or .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /%1/$1
```

This would map `project1.example.com/index.php` to directory `/var/www/project1/index.php`

`project2.example.com/index.php` to directory `/var/www/project2/index.php`

`project3.example.com/some/path/file.php` to directory `/var/www/project3/some/path/file.php`....

Comment: i want both urls, it contains different projects. where i want to add this codes ?

Comment: This will work for both. Anything $1.example.com/$2 will be rewritten to /var/www/$1/$2

Comment: Where i want to add these codes? please tell that also.

Comment: You can either put it in your VirtualHost definition or a .htaccess file. [This link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) has some good information